# Importing "Date" data type to Realm from CSV

Tags: swift, excel, realm

I want to import "Date" data type from CSV file. My CSV file looks like this:

[image]

"Time" column should be Date data type. But Realm thinks it's string. Realm file looks like this:
[image]

Later I am going to use Realm database in my swift application. Is there any way to make things work?

Comment: You need to convert it to a Date object using a DateFormatter.

Comment: It's a string because it's not a format that is recognized. The simplest solution is to make it a recognizable format before importing - a standard Realm Date format of `2021-02-16T18:00:32.408Z`